# HTML5 Layer On Top of Native Mobile App

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile

I wanted to ask a question to all you experts out there in mobile app development. I'm not a mobile (iOS or Android) developer myself, so I'd like to ask those of you that are comfortable with programming apps.

I was wondering if it was at all possible to layer HTML5 ON TOP of a native app, if that makes sense. I'm looking for a way to create an add-on to an already built HTML5 app if that's done through a JS add-on or whatever like it's already done on websites. This would allow me to make changes to the add-on (which takes up screen space) whenever I need to via traditional web programming.

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you're asking is what's the best way to drop an HTML5 web app within an already-functioning native app?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you're question correctly, but if you're simply looking for a way to integrate a web-based content made with HTML5 on a native app, you can use UIWebView. Just add it on your native app and load your HTML5 web app.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to take a look at http://www.phonegap.com which is designed to solve the problem of packaging web apps to look like native apps and fill in api holes